# How can I refer to a custom content type in an article while also dynamically displaying more information?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am building a website that will feature articles from many non-users, so these can be best described as "Guest Authors". So instead of adding too many users to my site, I would like to work with a custom content type (or whichever way you guys recommend).

What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Have custom field in Articles that refers to the Content Type "Guest Author Profile Page"
2. Once a "Guest Author" has been selected: At the end of an article, based on the selected "Guest Author", display a content block with the first name/last name of the author, their profile image, the short biography, a few social media links and a link to the Profile Page of the Guest Author.
3. Have a link to the "Guest Authors" Page, where I can display a grid of all the "Guest Authors". This grid contains their first name/last name, profile image, social media links and a link to their profile page.
4. The profile page that contains the following information, that is also used in the cases mentioned above: profile image, title (= full name), first name/last name fields, body, short biography (= excerpt), social media links.

It was easy to setup the custom content type and add fields to it, and I am also able to now select a guest author when creating an article, but I am having trouble getting all this other information displayed dynamically at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Can you share any code?  it's pretty hard to help (at all) without an idea of what your code looks like.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel – No code. This is just site-building.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I get what you mean, but so far I have not written any code, I am in the process of setting up the site

Comment: @leymannx Thats exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to choose a different field formatter for your reference field in the article's display settings. Choose "Rendered entity". You may also want to choose a different view mode maybe (to not display the full profile but certain fields you've prepared in the "Guest Authors" display settings for the corresponding view mode - here Teaser).

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to select which fields are being displayed as the rendered entity? Selecting "Teaser" does not allow me to display some of the other necessary fields.

I have now tried to create a new view with my preferred fields and render it as that, but I am not able to select this view as a format.

Comment: @jafi – Don't mix up view and view mode. Do you see in my screenshot just beneath the tab bar there's another bar "Default - RSS - Teaser". Go to your "Guest Author" display settings and select "Teaser" (which is a view mode) and then select which fields you want to display for this view mode.

Comment: I see! Thank you!